# how can I redirect example.com/ch to a subdirectory /rootdir/ch/?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have issue with url rewrite.
I have a site example.com that has a wordpress installed.

I want to have another wordress instance in the subdirectory "/ch-wordpress/" and serve it via url "example.com/ch/....".

I know there are a lot of question concerning url rewrite, but I wasn't able to find the one that can help me. Will be very thankful if anyone could help me a bit.

Here is a currect url rewrite text

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/culture-news/(.*)$ /cognac-news/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/bottles/(.*)$ /cognac-reviews/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/rare-bottle-price-worth-information/(.*)$ /your-cognac-bottle/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/history-region-production/(.*)$ /what-is-cognac/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/cognac-drinks-cocktails/(.*)$ /cognac-drinks-cocktails/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget about .htaccess there's an easier way, creante an index.php in your public_html and paste this

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com/ch/....');
?
>
```

it will redirect the index to the directory that you want

**EDIT**

you would like to redirect example.com/ch/$1" to subfolder "/ch/

okay then, you have a folder called **$1** create an index.php and place it in **$1**

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com/ch/');
?
>
```

even if **$1** is a file and not a folder, you could place the code in it and you'll be redirected when you go to it

Just try it to see how it works.

Comment: But I still want the main site "example.com" to function.

Comment: what do you mean? you want to redirect from example.com to example.com/folder and you you want to go to example.com at the same time? Please would you explain? you can delete the index.php

Comment: I would like to redirect the "example.com/ch/$1" to subfolder "/ch/"

Comment: thanks you very much but this is not exactly what you are saying!
I am just not into a mod_rewrite thing, but I am web developer with 4 years of field experience. Ehh maybe it is time to look at the mod_rewrite rules.